# How to solve a problem with the automatic table of contents of LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}

\ourtitlepage           
\tableofcontents    
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\emptypage}{\clearpage}   

\part{Calificación}     
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\emptypage}{\clearpage}   

\chapter{Plan de Calificación}
    \include{plan_calificacion}
    \include{registro_firmas} 
    \include{hoja_aprobaciones}

(.....)

\chapter{Reporte de Calificación}
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\emptypage}{\clearpage}   
    \include{reporte_calificacion}
    \include{hoja_aprobaciones}
    \include{desvios}

\chapter{Plan para mantener el estado calificado}
    \clearpage
    \include{mantenimiento_calificacion}    
    \include{hoja_aprobaciones}

\end{document}
```

Repeating `\include{hoja_aprobaciones}` the table of contents takes only one item and repeats the number of section (5.2.) and page (142) in all the instances.

> ```
> I Calificación                                                  4
> 1. Plan de Calificación                                         5
> 1.1. Plan de Calificación . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
> 1.2. Registro de rmas . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . 10
> 5.2. Hoja de aprobaciones . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 142
> 4. Reporte de Calificación                                    125
> 4.1. Reporte de la calificación . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 126
> 5.2. Hoja de aprobaciones . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 142
> 4.3. Reporte de desvíos . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 129
> 5. Plan para mantener el estado calificado                    139
> 5.1. Plan para mantener el estado calificado . . . . . . . .  140
> 5.2. Hoja de aprobaciones . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 142
> 5.3. Control de Cambios . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 143
> 5.4. Informe complementario al control de cambios . . . . . . 148
> 5.5. Informe de servicio técnico  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 150
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The language on this site is English, not Spanish. Please rephrase your question in English! Please complete your code above -- it's not compilable for us!

Comment: Si necesitas una mano con el inglés, podemos editar la pregunta, pero tienes que poner un ejemplo de documento y subdocumento que podamos compilar y reproducir el error para darte una solución. Por lo pronto, si "hoja_aprobaciones" es una parte del capítulo deberías usar `\input`,  no `\include`.

Comment: Fran gracias por tu ayuda!! El problema se resolvió colocando \input en vez de \include.

Comment: Hello Fran! Sorry, my english is very poor. I would like write an answer but I dont know use this site. It is the first time I do a question here. And I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Candela De nada. Entonces me permito editar tu pregunta para que encaje con las normas de esta web,  sin inglés y sin dar las gracias (aquí hay que ir al grano, el agradecimiento va implícito si aceptas y votas por la respuesta). Más abajo tienes mi respuesta formal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors and both that can be deduced of the excellent answers to  [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

1) First error was  use **`\include{}` instead of `\input{}`** for any chunk of text below a whole chapter because insert a `\clearpage` before and after the included code, and usually you do not want this for a section, a table or a few paragraphs.

2) Supposing that was fine insert a `\clearpage` before and after a section, the second error was use **`\include{hoja_aprobaciones}` several times**. Even if you want to show exactly the same content many times, unlike `\input{}`, each of these commands make its own auxiliar file (`hoja_aprobaciones.aux`). But done in triplicate, obviously only the last remain in the hard disk after the first compilation, so the information of the last `.aux` file will be:

```
\setcounter{page}{142}
(....)
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\setcounter{section}{2}
(....)
```

An finally this  information is used  for the table of contents in the second compilation ... again and again.

Comment: Hi, can you translate the question as well? It will be more helpful for others. Thanks.

Comment: I am doing this ... just a moment :)